# Ошибка при переносе проекта с VS10 на VS12

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ооп

При переносе проекта с VS10 на VS12 нструкции вида ниже, компилятор считает неправильными

```
Type2
{
  char ch[2];
public:
  Type2(char ch1, char ch2);
};  
//... some code  
Type MyFunction(Type2 obj);  
//... some code  
MyFunction( {'a', 'c'} ); // error place
```

Неужели везде теперь исправлять `MyFunction( {'a', 'c'} );` на
`MyFunction( Type2('a', 'c') );`

Comment: Хм, оказывается, это компилируется gcc: http://ideone.com/BrlDgp. Ну, переходите на свежую 2015-ую студию, у неё поддержка стандарта лучше.

Comment: @VladD извините, а почему оно должно не компилироваться? Это uniform initialization введенное в C++11. Другое дело непонятно, как это компилировалось у автора в VS10, если там нет поддержки C++11

Comment: В 2013 студии это успешно компилируется. 2012 тоже должна поддерживать начиная с обновления Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP,

Comment: В 2012 студии обновление 4 не собирается. В 2010 кстати тоже. Могу лишь посоветовать автору исправить все на MyFunction( Type2('a', 'c') ); Для меня MyFunction( {'a', 'c'} ); достаточно странное выражение.

Comment: @neitron Объясните мне, как это могло компилироваться в MS VC++ 2010?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, я прошу прощение за невнимательность, даный код создан в 13, но использовался toolset v100, поэтому я сделал неправильный вывод. Спасиб за советы )

Comment: @neitron Вероятно списки инициализации не поддерживаются в 12 версии. Только и всего.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow так и есть, прийдеться править все 306 мест в коде ((

Comment: @zenden2k: Ну, я не знал об этой фиче, всё же я редко работаю с C++.